# Android task/stack: why new task created in this case?

Tags: android, back-stack

I'm trying to get clear about task/back stack on Android at http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html.

When reach the part below i have some question. Please take a look on it first (or go to the link above to read all the post)

> However, by touching Up from the compose activity, the user indicates
>   a desire to remain within Gmail. Gmail's conversation list activity
>   appears, and a new Task B is created for it. New tasks are always
>   rooted to Home, so touching Back from the conversation list returns
>   there.

[image]

> Task A persists in the background, and the user may return to it later
>   (for example, via the Recents screen). If Gmail already had its own
>   task running in the background, it would be replaced with Task B—the
>   prior context is abandoned in favor of the user's new goal.

Now, get back to this question.

- Why does it create new task B in this case? (when user touching Up from the compose activity)
- What does it means by "it would be replaced with Task B"

Could you help to make it clear, please!?

Comment: [Check this link, that's because recent task have change in lollipop](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the usefull link, i already on it last hour. But in this question i try to practice it by myself with and Kitkat device. And the result is the same as mentioned on docs. So, i means that it happen with pre-lolipop devices. And i still don't understand why it create new task in this case?